US treasuries TRACE
For all trades on US Treasuries made through RFQs, all the trades should be reported to TRACE to have post-trade transparency.
But is TRACE then available to the public? or is it just for SEC?
If it's not made public I am wondering why it's not the case, because it would help institutions like banks to deliver bad quotes to toxic clients (for example clients that send simultaneous buy/sell RFQs to capture the spread without any risk).

It is publicly available as of very recently.
https://www.finra.org/rules-guidance/notices/24-06

According to https://www.finra.org/investors/insights/what-is-TRACE

U.S. Treasury securities, which represent the latest expansion of the program, are also reported to TRACE though currently aren’t publicly available.

See also https://www.finra.org/filing-reporting/trace/data

Thank you! Helps a lot. Any clues why it's not publicly available?

According to the news @dm21 found, it looks like it's becoming available. I don't know why it wasn't right away, but knowing FINRA, I suspect lack of funds/resources to do it sooner.
